# How do I specify flag for public ssh key for Docker Machine create command?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-machine

I've got EC2 instance up and running with public ssh key allowed in `authorized_keys` file sitting in the instance.

Private and public key are sitting in my `~/.ssh` directory. I named public key `public.pub`.

This is how I'm running it:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=18.122.150.170 --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/public.pub app-prod
```

that gives me:

```
/home/mark/.ssh/public.pub.pub: no such file or directory
```

Because `.pub` seems to be appended to it automatically I went ahead with:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=18.122.150.170 --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/public app-prod
```

that gave me:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "SSH key does not exist: \"/home/mark/.ssh/public\""
```

And the key **is** in the `.ssh` directory.

According to the guide below I'm supposed to supply a path to private key:

```
docker-machine create \
    --driver generic \
    --generic-ip-address=$IP_ADDRESS \
    --generic-ssh-user $USERNAME \
    --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/$PRIVATE_KEY \
    zdocker
```

if so, why then `.pub` is being appended to it ?

Any ideas as to what's happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tilda symbol resolved incorrectly. Try it with full path to SSH key, or with $HOME as replacement.
Also, you probably missed ssh-user param, that's important.

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=18.122.150.170 --generic-ssh-key $HOME/.ssh/public --generic-ssh-user your_user app-prod
```